# Regex to match a name starting with a specific set of strings

Tags: regex, invoice2data

Is it possible to match only the first string that occurs when specifying a specific subset of strings? I.e: `SRL`

```
SC FAN COURIER EXPRESS SRL                DISTRIBUTION SERVICES
J40/4014/2001 - RO13838336                MANAGEMENT SRL
                                          SC FAN COURIER EXPRESS SRL
                                          Operator FAN
```

What I want `DISTRIBUTION SERVICES MANAGEMENT SRL`

What I get `['', 'DISTRIBUTION SERVICES']`

What I'm trying `SRL(.*)\n`

[Demo](http://regexr.com/64v47)

Comment: What is first string and what is specific subset?

Comment: Try `(?m)SRL *([A-Z][A-Z ]+)\r?\n.*? ([A-Z][A-Z ]+)$` and concat Group 1 and Group 2 values. Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fldmpz/3).

Comment: Did it work?...